# Angular date problems

Tags: angularjs

Please see the following example: https://plnkr.co/edit/SGa2xy7M2OuFYOVkeuYe?p=preview

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input ng-model="flight.date" name="date" type="date" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="" max="<% Date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' %>" ng-change="changeDate()">
    </div>
    <% flight.date | date %>
    <% flight.date | date : medium : PST %>
</div>
```

I'm in GMT+2 timezone (CEST) and GMT+1 in winter time (CET).

When I select today from the input field (Jun 30 2016) the output Angular produces is UTC time. So it subtracts 2 hours from the actual time. But because we're only selecting the date the time is always 00:00:00.

So subtracting 2 hours from 00:00:00 will result in a date of the day before.

How do I fix that? I tried manually adding the time to that timestamp which works. But then the problem still exists between midnight and 2 AM.

Thanks!

[EDIT]
I'm currently using the following workaround:

Since we only need the date I'm just manually setting the time to 6PM so the 1 or 2 hour difference doesnt cause the date to change.

```
d.setHours('18', '00', '00');
```

Comment: If you are using dates and timezones a lot you could look into moment.js. I used it with angular 1.*

Comment: I don't understand why you want to fix something that is not broken. A date is always relative to your current location. When you want to show the date you entered, just use the `date` filter (as you already did) and it will show correctly. So what exactly is wrong about that?

Comment: This application is used internally so the timezone is always the same for us. I'm posting the result of the HTML5 input field to an external API.

So when Angular has the 30th and decides to subtract 2 hours by converting it to UTC it can show as the 29th instead.

Comment: Angular 1. See the example.

Comment: Again: This works as intended when you add the `date` filter (which is missing in the plunkr). It shows "Jun 30, 2016" and I am in the same timezone as you are.

Comment: @str true, the `date` filter helps, but when you store that date and view it in another timezone it might cause problems. If you always want to see the same date, regardless of where you are, you have to fix the timezone and do not rely on the browser's default timezone. It depends on the use case though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JavaScript Date instance is always relative to your current location. However, you only want to use the day-part and not the time-part, so what you could do is always use one and the same timezone when inputing and displaying the date. Just choose a timezone, e.g. UTC. You can make sure that the time will be inputted using UTC (instead of the browser's default) by adding that as a model option:

```
<input ng-model="flight.date" ng-model-options="{timezone:'UTC'}">
```

Make sure that you also use that timezone when displaying the date:

```
<% flight.date | date:'mediumDate':'UTC' %>
```

See my fork with this update of your Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/LqZv7olKCl12OjDMvicF?p=preview

Comment: Adding ng-model-options="{timezone:'UTC'}" works perfectly. Bloody hell I should have found that yesterday :P

Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, don't underestimate the importance of my second code fragment though. Otherwise your applications will have the same kind of problem but then for time zones that are before GMT (e.g. United States). If you always want to show the same date, regardless of where someone uses the application, you have to fix the timezone for the input as well as for displaying it.